# Undefined method on staging environment, works fine locally

Tags: ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

Having some issues with my staging environment at the moment. I have my app on Heroku (both staging and production). It works perfectly on local, but when I push it to the staging environment I keep getting an undefined method for category_id.

I have reset the databases, run my migrations and put the seeds in to no avail. The only thing I can think is there is something wrong with my product model but I haven't changed that part of the app since I last pushed it to production (works fine with the current version on there).

Is there any chance that one of my migrations is not going through? That's the only thing I can think of.

Product model:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :subcategory

mount_uploader :product_image, ProductImageUploader

validates :title, :description, presence: true
validates :title, uniqueness: true
validates :image_url, allow_blank: true, format: { with: %r{\.(gif|jpg|png)\Z}i, message: 'must be a URL for GIF, JPG or PNG image.'}
validates :subcategory_id, presence: true
end
```

Products Controller:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter :authorize, only: [:show, :index]
  before_action :set_product, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /products
  # GET /products.json
  def index
    @products = Product.order("title ASC")
    @categories = Category.all
    @subcategories = Subcategory.order("title ASC")
  end

  # GET /products/1
  # GET /products/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /products/new
  def new
    @product = Product.new
  end

  # GET /products/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /products
  # POST /products.json
  def create
    @product = Product.new(product_params)

    respond_to do |format|
     if @product.save
       format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully created.' }
       format.json { render json: @product, status: :created, location: @product }
     else
       format.html { render action: 'new' }
       format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
     end
   end
 end

 # PATCH/PUT /products/1
 # PATCH/PUT /products/1.json
 def update
   respond_to do |format|
    if @product.update(product_params)
      format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { head :ok }
    else
      format.html { render action: 'edit' }
      format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

# DELETE /products/1
# DELETE /products/1.json
def destroy
  @product.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to products_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

 private
   # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
   def set_product
     @product = Product.find(params[:id])
   end

   # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
   def product_params
     params.require(:product).permit(:title, :description, :image_url, :product_image, :subcategory_id, :category_id)
   end
 end
```

The view that is causing the error message:

```
=form_for(@product) do |f|
-if @product.errors.any?
    #error_explanation
        %h2
            =pluralize(@product.errors.count, "error")
            prohibited this product from being saved:

        %ul
        -@product.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
            %li
                =msg
        %br

.field
    =f.label :title
    %br
    =f.text_field :title, size: 100
    %br

.field
    =f.label :description
    %br
    =f.text_area :description, cols: 100, rows: 10
    %br

.field
    =f.label :product_image
    =f.file_field :product_image

.field
    =f.label :category_id
    %br
    =f.collection_select(:category_id, Category.all, :id, :title)
    %br

.field
    =f.label :subcategory_id
    %br
    // =f.collection_select(:subcategory_id, Subcategory.all, :id, :title)
    %select{:id => "product_subcategory_id", :name => "product[subcategory_id]", :disabled => "disabled"}
        %option
            Select a category first...
    %br

.actions
    %br
    =f.submit
    %br
    %br

:javascript
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("select#product_category_id").change(function(e) {
            var val = $(this).val();

            var subCatSelect = $("select#product_subcategory_id");
            subCatSelect.empty();

            subCatSelect.append("<option>Loading...</option>");

            $.get("/subcategories.json?category="+val)
            .done(function(response) {
                subCatSelect.empty();
                if (response.length > 0) {
                    $.each(response, function(k,v) {
                        subCatSelect.append("<option id='"+v.id+"'>"+v.title+"</option>");
                        subCatSelect.removeAttr("disabled");
                    });
                } else {
                    subCatSelect.attr("disabled", "disabled");
                    subCatSelect.append("<option>No Subcategories</option>");
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

And the error message:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `category_id' for #<Product:0x007f64ab47c1d0>):
30:   .field
31:     =f.label :category_id
32:     %br
33:     =f.collection_select(:category_id, Category.all, :id, :title)

app/views/products/_form.html.haml:33:in `block in _app_views_products__form_html_haml__3508934121535598535_70035173692040'
app/views/products/_form.html.haml:1:in `_app_views_products__form_html_haml__3508934121535598535_70035173692040'
app/views/products/new.html.haml:7:in `_app_views_products_new_html_haml__3953831312052620477_70035173605140'
```

Comment: What does `RAILS_ENV=staging bundle exec rake db:abort_if_pending_migrations` return?

Answer (score 0):

It may be an issue with the naming conventions in your asset pipeline.

Try precompiling your asset pipeline befor pushing to Heroku:

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
git commit -a -m "Prempile assets for release"
git push
git push heroku master
```

Here's some more info from Heroku on this:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline

Not sure if this will fix it, but it's very easy to try it.  I've found that this fixes most of problems moving from development/test to production.

Hope this helps!

Comment: No luck unfortunately. I'm not too sure what happened but when I cleared the heroku DB, re-ran my migrations and seeds it decided to work.... I have no idea what happened.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure what happened but when I cleared the heroku DB, re-ran my migrations and seeds it decided to work.... I have no idea what happened.